# Change value of variable in GameViewController (SpriteKit Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I created a UIScrollView in class GameViewController in which Subviews are scenes. When user enters a particular scene and presses a specific button ScrollView must stop scrolling.
How can I do this?

Example of code:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
  ...
}
class GameScene: SKScene {
  //Here we have button and if we will push it 
  //then scrollView.scrollEnabled must be false in class GameViewController.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make new class with this code

```
class Data {
struct gameScene {
    static var ButtonPressed:Bool = false 
}
}
```

Then make some changes in your code

```
 var gameScene: GameScene!

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
         gameScene = GameScene()
      }

       @IBAction func butPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        Data.gameScene.buttonPressed = true
    println("Pressed from GameViewController")
}

     override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

         if (Data.gameScene.buttonPressed == true) {

              println("Pressed from GameScene")

                 Data.gameScene.buttonPressed = false
          }
          }
```

You can call to this variable anywhere in your project with this code

```
                   Data.gameScene.buttonPressed
```